# Getting from pointwise convergence to uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

The question is the following: Let $f,f_1, f_2, ...$ be continuous real-valued functions on a compact metric space, $E$, where the $f_n$'s converge pointwise to $f$. We want to show that if $f_1(p) \leq f_2(p) \leq \dots$ for all $p \in E$ then the sequence of $f_n$'s converges uniformly.

I have been stuck on this problem for a while, and I cannot really get very far on it. I know that I can use Heine-Borel to say that $f, f_1, f_2\dots$ are all closed and bounded and that $f(p) = \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\{ f_n(p)\}.$ But I'm not sure where to go from here.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that some functions are closed and bounded?

Comment: Look up Dini's Theorem.

Comment: It's true $if$ the point-wise limit $f$ is continuous, This is called the Dini Theorem..... If $f$ is not continuous it may fail. For example $E=[0,1]$ with the usual metric $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $f_n(x)=1-x^n$.  In general if $(X,d)$ and $(Y,e)$ are metric spaces and a sequence $f_n:X\to Y$ of continuous $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f:X\to Y$ then $f$ is continuous..... But the limit of $1-x^n$ for $x\in [0,1)$ is $1$  but if $x=1$ then $1-x^n=0$ for all $n.$  So the limit function is discontinuous so the convergence can't be uniform.

Comment: Re my previous comment we can also show directly that $f_n(x)=1-x^n $ does not converge uniformly, as follows: $f_n(0)=1$ and $f_n(1)=0 $ so there exists $x_n\in (0,1)$ with $f_n(x)=1/2.$ Now $f(x_n)=\lim_{j\to \infty}f_j(x_n)=1.$  So for every $n$ we have $\sup \{|f(x)-f_n(x)|:x\in [0,1]\}\geq$  $\geq |f(x_n)-f_n(x_n)|=|1-1/2|=1/2 .$ So he convergence is not uniform